# Como posso "pegar" valores de um ou mais INPUT após ter clicado em um button SUBMIT em ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho andado com o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho um formulário de cadastro na qual o cliente deve entrar com seus dados obrigatoriamente através dos INPUTs, ao final há um button do tipo Submit, e ao clicá-lo seria disparado o evento click para aí sim pegar os dados. 
Acontece que ao clicar no button submit ele submete o formulário porém não executa o meu evento de click, segue um trecho do código:

aspx:

```
<form runat="server" name="sign">

     <input runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Seu nome" ID="userName"/>
     <br/>

     <input runat="server" type="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" ID="userEmail"/>
     <br/>

     <input runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Sua senha" ID="userPassword"/>
     <br/>

     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="sign" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="sign"/>

</form
```

C# (Code Behind):

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   string userNm;
   string userEml;
   string userPass;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void sign(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userNm = userName.Value;
        userEml = userEmail.Value;
        userPass = userPassword.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você esta utilizando WebForms?

Comment: Verifique se não há nada impedindo o disparo do botão, como por exemplo alguma validação. Tente adicionar "CausesValidation="false"" no botão apenas para testar.

Comment: Mas o método sign do evento `OnClick` é server side... ele vai precisar fazer um post para executar no servidor, você não está caindo lá? colocou um breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro assegure-se de que a Index.aspx inicia com a seguinte linha, que fará o bind da sua página de markup com o seu code-behind.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>
```

Se o código está exatamente como apresentado na pergunta você está com sérios problemas...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="sign" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="sign"/>
```

Isso já seria impossível e apresentaria um erro ao compilar o projeto porque você teria um método e um componente com o mesmo identificador. E o ideal seria dar nomes mais elusivos. E na verdade, no caso de eventos, você não deveria nem se preocupar e deixar o o VisualStudio nomear para você mantendo as convenções do .Net precionando Ctrl+Espaço quando o valor do evento estiver vazio `OnClick=""`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCadastrar" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="btnCadastrar_Click"/>
```

Ao final, você deverá ter algo como no exemplo abaixo, que foi testado e funciona:

**Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  runat="server">
        <div>
            <input runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Seu nome" id="userName" />
            <br />
            <input runat="server" type="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" id="userEmail" />
            <br />
            <input runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha" id="userPassword" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bntCadastrar" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="bntCadastrar_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string userNm, userEml, userPass = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 

    protected void bntCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userNm = userName.Value;
        userEml = userEmail.Value;
        userPass = userPassword.Value;
    }
}
```